# Windows Powershell command to access Zipfile

Tags: windows

What is the Windows equivalent command of

```
zcat file.zip | wc -l
```

I want to know the line count of a file inside a zipfile by using windows powershell command. Can you please tell me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Combining [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive) and [this blog entry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-a-powershell-cmdlet-to-count-files-words-and-lines/) this would look something like this:

```
Expand-Archive -Path ./example.zip -DestinationPath ./tmp/ -PassThru | % { Get-Content $_ | Measure-Object -Line}
```

Although it extracts the files, so you might want to remove ./tmp/ folder afterwards.

Comment: It gives This error:
..................................

Expand-Archive : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PassThru'.
At line:1 char:97
+ ... a\zipfile\sample.zip" -DestinationPath ./C:\tmpzip1 -PassThru | % { G ...
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Expand-Archive], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Expand-Archive

Comment: My bad - -PassThru was introduced in Powershell Core.
Please try this:
`Expand-Archive -Path ./example.zip -DestinationPath ./tmp/; 
Get-ChildItem -Path ./tmp/ | % { Get-Content $_.FullName | Measure-Object -Line}`